# Smtp.office365.com for OpenEdx

Tags: office365, openedx

I am facing a configuration problem with Office 365, the user did not receive email.

I've put my configuration in the file `{lms|cms}.{env|auth}.json`.

But the user still doesn't receive the email.

{lms|cms}.env.json :

```
"EMAIL_HOST": "smtp.office365.com", 
"EMAIL_PORT": 587, 
"EMAIL_USE_TLS": true,
```

Comment: I think the file should be name `lms.env.json` or `cms.env.json`, not `{lms|cms}.env.json`.

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to include a username and password for your Office 365 account, because smtp.office365.com is not going to let you send emails anonymously.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get this working you need to modify a few settings in four different files, then restart Apache:

- Navigate to the **edx/conf/** folder, the full path of which will depend on how you've installed it
- Edit **lms.env.json**
- Modify the following settings:

  1. **DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL:** *"Open-edX@Yourcompany.com"* - This is the email address you want emails to show as having been sent by. **NOTE:** This may not be the same as the mailbox's login credentials
  2. **EMAIL_HOST**: "smtp.office365.com"
  3. **EMAIL_PORT**: 587
  4. **EMAIL_USE_TLS**: true
- Edit **cms.env.json**
- Modify the following settings:

  1. **DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL:** *"Open-edX@Yourcompany.com"* - This is the email address you want emails to show as having been sent by. **NOTE:** This may not be the same as the mailbox's login credentials
  2. **EMAIL_HOST**: "smtp.office365.com"
  3. **EMAIL_PORT**: 587
  4. **EMAIL_USE_TLS**: true
- Edit **lms.auth.json**
- Modify the following settings:

  1. **EMAIL_HOST**: "smtp.office365.com"
  2. **EMAIL_PORT**: 587
  3. **EMAIL_USE_TLS**: true
  4. **EMAIL_HOST_USER**: "login@yourcompany.onmicrosoft.com" - This is the login you use to access webmail for the mailbox, and may be different or the same as the previously-used DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL setting
  5. **EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD**: The password you use to access webmail for the mailbox
- Edit **cms.auth.json**
- Modify the following settings:

  1. **EMAIL_HOST_USER**: "login@yourcompany.onmicrosoft.com" - This is the login you use to access webmail for the mailbox, and may be different or the same as the previously-used DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL setting
  2. **EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD**: The password you use to access webmail for the mailbox
- Restart Apache (or the server, if you're unsure how to)